# Electron WebSQl execute and close

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron, web-sql

I have an **Electron** Application. I open a new Electron Window with a HTML-Form to save some data in WebSQL Database.

For this it's a -Button with a style-id. The action will be added by jQuery click.

```js
jQuery(document).on('click', '#js-add-cat-button', function ()
        {
            var cat = {
                Title: jQuery('#category_title').val(),
                StartDate: jQuery('#category_startdate').val(),
                EndDate: jQuery('#category_enddate').val()
            };
            AddCategory(db, cat);
            jQuery('#form-addCategory')[0].reset();
            jQuery('#category_title').focus();
  });
```

This works fine. But **on the same** time, I'd liked to close this "add entry"-window. Because no more action is needed. My problem is, when I add also "window.close()" to JavaScript, the window will be closed without saving the data in websql.

I think the close action is executed faster than WebSQl write process.

So how can I close the window after the data will be really saved?

Comment: you can return a promess as a flag from your function to close the window or use a setTimeout to wait a few secs to save it.

Comment: Yap! Fine. That's a solution. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice, glad to help you :)